# Paste data from a different sheet after the last active row of the current sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy the values from A and B columns of the orders tab of the workbook and paste those values to the Duplicate warning settings tab after the last active row.

```
Public Sub My_Copy_Orders()
Dim Last_Row As Long
    Sheets("Duplicate warning Settings").Select
    Last_Row = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1).Row
    Sheets("Orders").Columns("A:B").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Duplicate warning Settings").Range("A" & Last_Row)
End Sub
```

It gives me an error
[image]

Comment: The only way you can copy over an entire column - i.e. with `Columns("A:B")` - is if you paste into the *first* row of the destination column. So don't copy the entire column....

Answer (score 0):

You're copying entire columns A & B (all 1,048,576 rows by two columns). Your destination is correctly using only the top-left corner as a reference point but since you are below the first row, you no longer have 1,048,576 rows worth of empty cells below the destination. Essentially you're trying to paste empty cells below the bottom of the worksheet.

Simply limit the source of the copy to the worksheet's usedrange.

```
with Sheets("Orders")
  intersect(.usedrange, .Columns("A:B")).Copy _
    Destination:=Sheets("Duplicate warning Settings").Range("A" & Last_Row)
end with
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below sub

```
Public Sub My_Copy_Orders()
Dim Last_Row As Range
Dim sht1, sht2 As Worksheet
Dim aRow, bRow As Long

    Set sht1 = Sheets("Duplicate warning Settings")
    Set sht2 = Sheets("Orders")
    Set Last_Row = sht1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

    aRow = sht2.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
    bRow = sht2.Range("B1").End(xlDown).Row

        If aRow > bRow Then
            sht2.Range("A1:B" & aRow).Copy Last_Row
        Else
            sht2.Range("A1:B" & bRow).Copy Last_Row
        End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Basic code using variables.

```
Dim wsSrc As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet, scrlRow As Long

Set wsSrc = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Orders")
Set wsDest = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Duplicate warning Settings")

srclRow = wsSrc.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row


Dim cpyRng As Range
Set cpyRng = Range("A1:B" & srclRow)

    cpyRng.Copy wsDest.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
```